# Is it secure to rely on "X-Forwarded-For" to restrict access by IP in Apache while using Cloudflare?

Tags: linux, apache, cloudflare

I'm restricting access to a directory to certain IP addresses using a .htaccess file like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"

<RequireAny>
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
</RequireAny>
```

That works fine in a normal server setup, however when using Cloudflare as a WAF proxy, it stops working since the server receives all requests proxied through Cloudflare's IP.

As a workaround, it's possible to use the "X-Forwarded-For" header to identify the client's "real" IP address, since Cloudflare passes this with all its requests:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"

SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For 1.2.3.4$ allowed

<RequireAny>
    Require env allowed
</RequireAny>
```

Is this a safe approach or is there a better/more secure way to limit access by client IP in Apache when Cloudflare is being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [IETF RFC 2616, Section 4.2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), a header can hold a comma separated list of values, and this is the case of `X-Forwarded-For` as  [Cloudflare uses it](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-).

> If an X-Forwarded-For header was already present in the request to
>   Cloudflare, Cloudflare appends the IP address of the HTTP proxy to the
>   header:
>
> ```
> Example: X-Forwarded-For: 203.0.113.1,198.51.100.101,198.51.100.102
> ```
>
> In the examples above, 203.0.113.1 is the original visitor IP address and
>   198.51.100.101 and 198.51.100.102 are proxy server IP addresses provided to Cloudflare via the X-Forwarded-For header.

It is customary to take the leftmost IP as the real one, but this isn't always the case.

If you go this way, you should check for a regex that matches your IP as

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^1\.2\.3\.4 allowed
```

(leftmost IP, escaping the dots)

## A better way (IMHO)

Cloudflare also sends the header `cf-connecting-ip` (which is meant to be the last IP to hit cloudflare before being sent to your machine) and I'd rather use that one.

> Is this a safe approach or is there a better/more secure way to limit
>   access by client IP in Apache when Cloudflare is being used?

There's a catch. In this scenario, you're telling Apache:

*"we have cloudflare in the middle so instead of your native way to tell the visitor's IP let's look at this custom header".*

**That custom header can be forged**. Absolutely. Therefore, you should also say:

*"this custom header should be taken as reliable if and only the request comes from a Cloudflare IP".*

[Cloudflare does explicitly list their IP ranges](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/)

Finally, you should use [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) instead of manually building a SetEnvIf rule.

Basically:

```
# /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/remoteip.conf
RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 173.245.48.0/20
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 103.21.244.0/22
...
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2606:4700::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2803:f800::/32
```

Alternatively, put the IP list in a separate file:

```
# /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/remoteip.conf
RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
RemoteIPTrustedProxyList conf/trusted-proxies.lst
```

and

```
# conf/trusted-proxies.lst
173.245.48.0/20
103.21.244.0/22
...
...
2803:f800::/32
2606:4700::/32
```

If said header doesn't come in the request, Apache falls back ro REMOTE_ADDR. Same goes for requests coming from untrusted IPs. If the header is present and comes from Cloudflare, you can simply do:

```
Require ip 1.2.3.4
```

This approach replaces the IP wherever you need to use it (logs, auth, etc) and gracefully falls back to original REMOTE_ADDR in edge cases.