# Block access in htaccess using X-Forwarded-For, when there are two ips

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to block using rules in htaccess as follows:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 173 \ .245 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 103 \ .21 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 103 \ .22 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 103 \ .31 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 141 \ .101 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 108 \ .162 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 190 \ .93 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 188 \ .114 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 197 \ .234 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 198 \ .41 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 162 \ .158 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 104 \ .16 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 172 \ .64 \." AllowAccess
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^ 131 \ .0 \." AllowAccess
Allow from env = AllowAccess
```

But this is not working for me, since I always get permission denied, when I make the request the server returns the following information:

```
varnish-request bal-7361 {"time": "[Jun / 25/2020: 23: 14: 52 +0000]", "status": "403", "bytes": "17", "method": " GET "," host ":" xxxx.com "," url ":" / "," query ":"? N = 62 "," referrer ":" - "," user_agent ":" Mozilla /5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 83.0.4103.116 Safari / 537.36 "," client_ip ":" 162.158.79.38 "," time_firstbyte ":" 0.004040 "," hitmiss ":" miss "," handling ":" miss "," forwarded_for ":" 201.246.98.193, 162.158.79.38 "," request_id ":" v-ace334b8-b739-11ea-a340-0285be1d8ea9 "," ah_log ": "", "ah_application_id": "", "ah_environment": "", "ah_trace_id": ""}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: By the way, X-Forwarded-For is the worst thing you could use for security. Try to use mod_remoteip as @Pandurang said. It is because, the X-Forwarded-For is set by the browser. And anyone (anyone at all), can change it to anything, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict using below configuration:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^1\.2\.3\.4 allowed
```

you should use mod_remoteip instead of manually building a SetEnvIf rule. Please refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314261/is-it-secure-to-rely-on-x-forwarded-for-to-restrict-access-by-ip-in-apache-whi) for more information.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that using X-Forwarded-For is so insecure.

Comment: Yet to find out if they tested it haha